# How to prevent the user after logout when he enter the url in address bar he should get the login page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have created a web application. Everything works fine.But, if the user is not logged in still they can have access to other jsp pages through url. I want to stop url access. I saw some example it shows the usage of filters. I'm new to filters I don't how to implement it. I'm using spring mvc

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use Spring security, you can check their [official documentation](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security#learn)

I think what you want is something that can be placed in your configuration class of [WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html)

In there, you can protect your pages from unauthenticated and unauthorized access by providing your implementation of `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method. This is the sample they provide on their [documentation page](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/):

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
             User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: We are not using the spring-security framework . Can u provide any other solutin

Comment: Well you would need to place a similar logic somewhere, for example if you are running your application in Tomcat, you could also do it there: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html

Or if your application is behind an API gateway for example, you could instead configure the access permissions there. It really depends on what tools you have currently and what tools are you allowed/ok with using